# How to compile data by date into one column

Tags: r

I need to change a dataframe that is has a variable arranged by date like this:

```
type Var_Day1 Var_Day2 Var_Day3
1   2   66  222
2   5   55  333
3   6   44  555
4   3   33  444
5   4   22  333
```

into a new dataframe with one column for the variable for all days. Something like this:

```
type Day Var
1   1   2
2   1   5
3   1   6
4   1   3
5   1   4
1   2   66
2   2   55
3   2   44
4   2   33
5   2   22
1   3   222
2   3   333
3   3   555
4   3   444
5   3   333
```

I tried the package reshape and function melt but I’m stuck. Here is my code:

```
install.packages("reshape")
library ("reshape")
data<-read.csv("data by day.csv",header=T)
newdata <- melt(data, id=c("type"))
```

Any suggestion?
Many thanks,
Diego

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr`. first we `gather` the data (same as melting) with type as the id variable (designated by `-type`). Then we get the numeric part out of the column headings using `extract_numeric`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>% gather(day, Var, -type) %>%
         mutate(day = extract_numeric(day))
   type day Var
1     1   1   2
2     2   1   5
3     3   1   6
4     4   1   3
5     5   1   4
6     1   2  66
7     2   2  55
8     3   2  44
9     4   2  33
10    5   2  22
11    1   3 222
12    2   3 333
13    3   3 555
14    4   3 444
15    5   3 333
```

Comment: Thanks jeremycg. For some reason tidyr doesn't seem to work.

Comment: try running `install.packages("tidyr")` and install.packages("dplyr")

Comment: Thanks. It works great!. I tried to read about mutate but I don't understand what it does. can you explain me why it is "extract_numeric(day)" and not "extract_numeric(var_day)"?

Comment: `mutate` is a way to modify columns in your data set - in this case I'm setting the column `day` to the output of the function `extract_numeric(day)`, which is the same as writing `data$day <- extract_numeric(data$day)` take a look at the [dplyr cheat sheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
library(reshape2)
data("LifeCycleSavings")
LifeCycleSavings$type <- 1:50
colnames(LifeCycleSavings)[1:5] <- paste0("var_day", 1:5)
melt(LifeCycleSavings, id.vars = "type") -> z
as.character(z$variable) -> z$variable
gsub("var_day", "", z$variable) -> z$day
z[,c("type", "day", "value")] -> z
colnames(z)[3] <- "var
```

Comment: Thanks, Chris. I don't quite understand the gsub part. What if instead of "value" I want to name it "var"?

Comment: i edited the answer to name it var...gsub is basically just striping the "Var_Day" from  Var_Day1, Var_Day2, Var_Day2 , etc.